# json decode and encode - iterate through multi dimensional array and remove key value if equals certain value

Tags: php, jquery, json

Basically the json output is this -output is from php.

```
[{"attr":{"id":"node_2","rel":"default"},"data":"C:","state":"closed"},{"attr":{"id":"node_3","rel":"drive"},"data":"D:","state":"closed"}]
```

so because rel is equal to default

```
{"attr":{"id":"node_2","rel":"default"},"data":"C:","state":"closed"}
```

I need to remove this from the array.

I have thought of maybe using

```
foreach($arr as $key => &$item) {
    if ($value['rel'] == 'default'{
        unset($arr[$key]);
```

This however, wont work for some reason. I have no idea if my method is the best way, or whether there is a better way to achieve this.
I also need to decode and encode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json_encode and json_decode to parse the json as Jesse Bunch said.

After i decoded the json you posted, it returned as an object. To call on an object you have to do things a bit diffrent.

```
$arr = json_decode('[{"attr":{"id":"node_2","rel":"default"},"data":"C:","state":"closed"},{"attr":{"id":"node_3","rel":"drive"},"data":"D:","state":"closed"}]');

foreach($arr as $key => $row)
{
    if ($row->attr->rel == 'default'){
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

The $arr does no longer contain the default rel

Comment: If you pass `TRUE` as the second parameter to `json_decode`, it'll return it as an array rather than an object of type `StdClass`.

Comment: Thank you so much Pilatus. I do believe that has worked. Is there a simple way to encode that again now. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, mutating an array while you're looping it is frowned upon. In PHP, there is nothing that say you cannot mutate an array while looping it. What you're doing is absolutely fine and probably the most efficient way of doing it.

As for encoding and decoding, see `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that this is not working though. Is there something simple I am missing.